# How to return jQuery result outside of the anonymous function?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsure why variable is undefined. Possible scope issue?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9337077/unsure-why-variable-is-undefined-possible-scope-issue)

I'm sorry for the bad title but I just don't know what else to call it. I hope my hacked together code will supply enough information. (Please feel free to laugh and point at me but don't forget to offer something constructive while you're at it.)

Line 24, 27, 31, and 43 are where my issue(s) lies. Line 27 contains the data I am expecting (and line 26 displays what I expect it to). However, I am trying to return that information to fetchResults on line 24 and that is pretty clearly not happening: fetchResults is empty.

I believe this is because line 27 is returning the result to the anonymous function on line 24 but from there it goes nowhere.

Line 43 is where I plan to use the result. (Yes, I added the lines numbers by hand.)

```
1 $(document).ready(function() {
2 
3   // Fetch XML generic fetch format
4   function genericFetch(entityType, fieldA, fieldB, valueX)
5   {   
6       function onFetchError(xhr, status, errorThrown)
7       {
8           var errormsg = $(xhr.responseXML).find('Message').text();
9
10          alert('CrmFetchKit-Error occured: ' +  errormsg);
11      }
12
13      var fetchxml = ['<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical">',
14                      ' <entity name="' + entityType + '">',
15                      '  <attribute name="' + fieldA + '" />',
16                      '  <attribute name="' + fieldB + '" />',
17                      '  <filter type="and">',
18                      '   <condition attribute="' + fieldA + '" operator="eq" value="' + valueX + '" />',
19                      '  </filter>',
20                      ' </entity>',
21                      '</fetch>'].join('');
22
23      // Action: load the account with a certain name
24      var fetchResults = CrmFetchKit.Fetch(fetchxml).then(function (results) {
25          /* success handler */
26          alert("results: " + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
27          return results;
28      }, onFetchError);
29      
30      alert("fetchResults: " + JSON.stringify(fetchResults, null, 4));
31      return fetchResults;
32  }
33
34
35  $('#ati_ittestingbutton2').click(function(){
36      var entityType = "product";
37      var fieldA = "productnumber";
38      var fieldB = "name";
39      var valueX = "SL64030";
40      
41      var fetchResults = genericFetch(entityType, fieldA, fieldB, valueX);
42      
43      alert("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(fetchResults, null, 4));
44      alert("fetchRes: " + fetchResults[0]['attributes']['productnumber']['value']);
45  });
46 });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of maybe a thousand other questions; you cannot return things from asynchronous functions, because they run asynchronously.

Comment: +1 for laughter access rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to agree with the initial comment replies - there are lots of variations on this here and elsewhere - but that probably doesn't help you unless you know what you are looking for.

So... Apologies if this is sucking eggs 101 but..

The function that you are calling to get your data is operating asynchronously ie, once called, it hands back control to the code that called it and goes off and does its thing - by the time it hits the return the world has moved on and isn't waiting for it anymore - that's the 'a' in ajax and it's a mistake that most of us have made (I know I did anyway...).

A couple of ways of getting round this. You could change to sync operation but this is a bad thing - it rather defeats the purpose of ajax and will result in the sky raining fishes and other portents of the apocalypse. Doesn't stop us doing it from time to time though...

The better way is to adapt your program flow so that the result handling code is called from the success or complete handlers.

Comment: I should have mentioned it but you did end up hitting the nail on the head: I looked at several other threads on this topic but because hey weren't close enough to what I was looking for I didn't get too far. But I do understand what you're saying about the asynch-ness of the whole thing so that's where I'll start looking. Head down and power through and all.